# Use Python to open cmd, get the result and proceed accordingly

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, pipe, stdin

I need a code where Python can invoke a `cmd` process, run a command.

I have to find whether that command succeeds or not and proceed accordingly in the python code.

The codes I have fount on stackoverflow deals only with opening cmd and running commands.

I don't want to use the `runas` as it requires admin privilege, which I have incorporated in my program later and should not be used here.(suggest it only if doesn't invoke a UAC and doesn't require admin privileges.

the only code I have found to run `cmd` without admin privilege is:

```
command = "cmd.exe" 
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

I don't know if the `proc` variable can be used to detect the return value or any other thing, guide me accordingly and suggest better code if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the result of `Popen` can be used to detect the return value and output, but it's easier to use `subprocess.run`. From the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

```
subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"])  # doesn't capture output

result = subprocess.run(["ls", "-l", "/dev/null"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) # returns a CompletedProcess
```

You can interrogate `result` (again, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess)):

```
result.returncode # process return code
result.stdout # std out from the process
```